# Why certein form of solution of heat equation cannot be used to estimate flux

Tags: partial-differential-equations, closed-form, heat-equation

Considering the 1-D semi-infinite domain,
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{\partial^2 T(x, t)}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{\alpha} \frac{\partial T(x, t)}{\partial t} \quad \text { in } \quad 0<x<\infty, \quad t>0 \\
& \mathrm{BC} 1: T(x=0, t)=f(t) \\
& \mathrm{BC} 2: T(x \rightarrow \infty, t)=0 \\
& \mathrm{IC}: T(x, t=0)=0
\end{aligned}
$$

The solution is given by

$$
T(x, t)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4 \pi \alpha}} \int_{\tau=0}^t \frac{f(\tau)}{(t-\tau)^{3 / 2}} \exp \left[-\frac{x^2}{4 \alpha(t-\tau)}\right] d \tau
$$

Then I notice that There's discontinuity at $x=0$, the integration of $
\int_{\tau=0}^t\left(f(\tau) /(t-\tau)^{3 / 2}\right) d \tau
$ does not exist since

$$
\int_{\tau=0}^t\left(f(\tau) /(t-\tau)^{3 / 2}\right) d \tau=\sqrt{4 \pi \alpha} \frac{f(t)}{x}
$$

Therefore we cannot calcute heat flux at surface, i.e.

$$
q_x^{\prime \prime}(x=0)=-\left.k \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right|_{x=0}
$$
is unstable.

I read some references saying that the solution is not a closed form and you can use chnage of variable to get a stable form of the heat flux. Can anyone please tell me what does 'closed form' mean and how to transform a solution to a closed form?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure the solution is correct as written because it doesn't satisfy the boundary condition $T(0, t) = 0 \ne f(t)$ for arbitrary $f$.

Comment: Exactly it doesn't satisfy because it's not a closed form. The solution itself is correct however its not continuous at the boundary.